# Using Windows Progress Dialogs in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, progressdialog

So I'm currently diving into the deep waters of .NET asynchronous task programming, progress reporting and cancellation. What I dont seem to find is a proper way of presenting the progress to a waiting user. Is it somehow possible to use the neat windows build in progress dialogs (for copying files etc) in WPF? I'm not a great friend of reinventing the wheel so using something that already exists seems like a better idea to me!

Comment: It is already built into the .NET Framework in everybody's [favorite namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.copydirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Well yeah but I'm searchin only the dialog which windows uses there for my general purpose of a task reporting progress and not really copying folders!

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try these links to understand usage of progress bars:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/393ac5/use-of-progressbar-in-wpf/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm well aware of the progress bar itself I was rather searching for a complete dialog to show, with text, caption, progressbar, animation etc.

Comment: Ok. You do have such Complete controls in Telerik. http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/track-and-status-controls-progressbar-overview.html